# i want to change "text1" to "text2" first click and change "text2" to "text1" second click by only single button

Tags: javascript

```js
function fun(){
  
  var read1 = document.getElementById("ddr");
  
  if(read1.innerHTML == "text2"){
    read1.innerHTML = "text1";
    
  }
  
  
  read1.innerHTML = "text2"
  
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="bt" onclick="fun()"> button </button>
  <p id="ddr">
    text1
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to change "text1" to "text2" first click and change "text2" to "text1" second click by only single button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing return statement:

```
function fun(){
  var read1 = document.getElementById("ddr");

  if(read1.innerHTML == "text2"){
    read1.innerHTML = "text1";
    return; //return here
  }
  read1.innerHTML = "text2"
}
```

or with `else`:

```
function fun(){
  var read1 = document.getElementById("ddr");

  if(read1.innerHTML == "text2"){
    read1.innerHTML = "text1";
  } else {
    read1.innerHTML = "text2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed the `else` statement.

```js
function fun(){
    var read1 = document.getElementById("ddr");
  
    if(read1.innerHTML == "text2"){
        read1.innerHTML = "text1";        
    }
    else{    
        read1.innerHTML = "text2"
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="bt" onclick="fun()"> button </button>
  <p id="ddr">
    text1
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```